# How to apply more-like-this query on a subset of documents in a index

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I subset documents in a index by a query and then apply my more-like-this query on this subset of documents ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them those two queries in different ways. In your case using a `bool query` will do that.
[Compound Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/compound-queries.html)
[Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)